fastAPI Python server not listening to port:8000
Hello am getting this error trying to start my python server what could be the solution
ERROR:    [Errno 13] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 8000): [winerror 10013] an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
trying to start a python server on port:8000 but its shutting itself down

Does it work with other ports?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the full traceback error.

There could be many different reasons behind this, such as:

Another service is already using that port. So you should check if the port is being used by another program or not. netstat -aon | findstr :8000 This will return if any program is being using this 8000 port you should kill this.

Run VS code or any other editor as Administrator: This could be another where if you had stored your code editor in diff file and your python in another file windows would give you permission issue. So try running as administrator and see if that fixed your problem or not.

Firewall or Antivirus Blocking: Another reason could windows firewall or anti-virus software (if installed any) is blocking your port. So, try temporarily disabling your antivirus/firewall to see if the issue is resolved.


P.S: There is a high chance your port is being used by another service or program, so simply changing to another port or killing 8000 port would solve your problem.

Thanks this worked . I needed to kill an instance from docker which was listening at the same port to allow it run

You can kill a running port using:
npx kill-port 8080 for windows if you have npm. or  taskkill /PID 2660 /F 
for linux you can just run kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8000)
